# Win10: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

Whenever I am trying to import tensorflow on **Anaconda prompt**, it is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried installing Visual C++ 2015 version and reinstalling tensorflow using "`conda install tensorflow`", it keeps giving message:

```
(base) C:\Users\Dell>conda install tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

All requested packages already installed.

## What should I do?

Python code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: See [similar issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794) here.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly these errors come about when you forgot to *activate* your anaconda prompt first. So: `conda activate environment_name`, followed by a `conda install tensorflow`, then launch your python.exe by typing `python.exe` in your anaconda prompt, and type`import tensorflow as tf`.

Comment: I have activated anaconda environment, everything is installed on my 'base' environment. One more thing, tensorflow was working fine until I installed tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the right version of tensorflow-gpu, with CUDNN 9.0? If you use a "too new" tensorflow version you will get errors. Or did you manage to resolve the issue already?