# Pyinstaller not generating .exe file if my script contains imports from .py modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I'm trying to generate an .exe file from my .py script using pyinstaller, but I realised after several attempts that it only works when I exclude certain imports: it works fine with libraries whose files have .pyi extensions, while it doesn't generate the .exe file if I import modules from files with .py extensions.
For instance:

```
#### These are fine because .pyi
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Thread
import decimal as dec
import math

#### These don't let Pyinstaller generate an .exe --> Most likely because these are .py files, as opposed to .pyi!!
# from PIL import ImageTk, Image
# import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
# from matplotlib import style
# from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
```

This way, with the second group commented out, I get pyinstaller to work, but obviously the app returns errors when I run it. If I uncomment them, though, pyinstaller doesn't generate any .exe at all.

I tried using --hidden-import and other options of pyinstaller, but nothing seems to work, has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

I am using Windows, Python3.8, pyinstaller3.6 and developing on Spyder3, if this is of any relevance.

Thank you in advance to anyone who will answer!

Comment: What options are you calling pyinstaller with? And does it just not give a .exe or is there an error? if there is an error displayed please add that to the post.

Comment: No error given, it just doesn't create any executable, nor any _pycache_ folder
I've tried several options, such as:
`C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller --hidden-import=PIL --hidden-import=matplotlib -F H2.py`
`C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller --onefile H2.py`
and more

Comment: Also tried to generate a .spec first, modify it and then use pyinstaller command on the .spec file, still no differet outcome: the only thing that seems to work is commenting out the aforementioned imports. In that case, it works well with any options.

Comment: `.pyi` is a python stub; no code. They actually point to a `.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all those who tried to answer, I finally sorted this thing out and it was much trickier than I thought, as the problem wasn't in my code or in the modules, but in the configuration of my environment. I had basically forgotten to activate the base environment. Obviously it worked fine as long as I ran it in Spyder, but messed it up when trying to use the command prompt.
Once fixed this (thank to the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133906/win10-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)) I managed to create an .exe file that runs just fine (although still struggling with uploading images).